# Remove everything after the question mark in the URL?

Tags: redirects, query-string

Is there any way to redirect a page with a question mark in the URL, to the same page, but with everything after the question mark removed?

For example:

From: `/residential-properties/projectname/?utm_source=moneycontrol&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=project`

To: `/residential-properties/projectname/`

I hope you get my question.

Comment: Understanding **why** you want to do this would help us answer with a potentially more effective solution. Otherwise this is an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question. For example, you might be better off just updating [URL Parameters](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters) instead.

Answer (score 2):

A literal question mark in the URL marks the start of the *query string*, so you can test if the query string contains anything and redirect if it does. Using Apache mod_rewrite in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` pattern matches against the URL-path, which notably excludes the query string.

The `?` (question mark) on the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution effectively removes the query string from the rewritten URL by creating an empty query string. The question mark itself does not appear in the resulting URL. If you are on Apache 2.4+ then you can use the `QSD` flag instead (Query String Discard).

If you only need to do this for a specific URL, then change the `RewriteRule` accordingly:

```
RewriteRule ^(residential-properties/projectname/)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Even easier:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```