# Redirect URL to the same page with parameter

Tags: url, url-rewriting, canonical-url

I have this url in my blog:

```
http://www.myweb.com/
```

and would like to change into:

```
http://www.myweb.com/?lang=en
```

all the URl, of course, in the same page = `index.php`
I need to use param `lang=en` to grab and change the page into a canonical page which I decide at `http://www.myweb.com/index.php?lang=en`. I've done with this follows and it didn't give it work. please.

I also try this: [Redirect Page after question mark to the same page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85073/redirect-page-after-question-mark-to-the-same-page)
but, browser reported that page isn't redirecting properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would help?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=en(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myweb\.com\/index.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?lang=en [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Only for homepage on addon domain (assuming your addon domain is `http://YourAddOn.Domain.com`):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=en(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^YourAddOn\.Domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?lang=en [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: There are tons of htaccess in related to this bored issue, but I still get confused of using and not work. It's very important for me. you did it. it works like I do wish ^_^. thanks soooooooo much.

Comment: but how to make it work in homepage only. that adds all URLs.

Comment: i updated my answer: assuming your homepage is www.myweb.com/index.html

Comment: it removes the url param (both homepage & sub dir). my web is on addon domain. does it affect it?

Comment: upd: homepage on addondomain